# How to split string to substrings with given length but not breaking sentences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I have a string with a large text and need to split it into multiple substrings with length <= N characters (as close to N as it's possible; N is always bigger than the largest sentence), but I also need not to break the sentences.

For example, if I have N = 80 and given text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in tellus quam. Nam sit amet iaculis lacus, non sagittis nulla. Nam blandit quam eget velit maximus, eu consectetur sapien sodales. Etiam efficitur blandit arcu, quis rhoncus mauris elementum vel.
```

I want to get list of strings:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in tellus quam."
"Nam sit amet iaculis lacus, non sagittis nulla."
"Nam blandit quam eget velit maximus, eu consectetur sapien sodales."
"Etiam efficitur blandit arcu, quis rhoncus mauris elementum vel."
```

And also I want this to work with English and Russian.

How to achieve this?

Comment: If N is always larger than the largest sentance, just do `mystring.split('.')`

Comment: @gogaz "as close as possible to N"

Comment: @gogaz there can be two sentences which summary length fit in N characters (I need each string's length to be as close to N as possible).

Comment: Define 'break the sentence'. You mean breaking a word? or actually breaking a sentence (i.e. breaking before a  `.` )

Comment: @RafaelC yep, I need each sentence to fit into one string, it's unacceptable to split sentence to two strings. But one string can contain multiple sentences.

Comment: Then splitting by `.` and combining consectuive sequences such that `len(newseq) <= N` sounds like the way to go

Comment: @RafaelC Just as I thought ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps I'd take:

- Initiate a list to store the lines and a current `line` variable to store the string of the current line.
- Split the paragraph into sentences - this requires you to `.split` on `'.'`, remove the trailing empty sentence (`""`), strip leading and trailing whitespace (`.strip`) and then add the fullstops back.
- Loop through these sentences and:

  - if the sentence can be added onto the current line, add it
  - otherwise add the current working line string to the list of lines and set the current line string to be the current sentence

---

So, in Python, something like:

```
para = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer in tellus quam. Nam sit amet iaculis lacus, non sagittis nulla. Nam blandit quam eget velit maximus, eu consectetur sapien sodales. Etiam efficitur blandit arcu, quis rhoncus mauris elementum vel."
lines = []
line = ''
for sentence in (s.strip()+'.' for s in para.split('.')[:-1]):
    if len(line) + len(sentence) + 1 >= 80: #can't fit on that line => start new one
        lines.append(line)
        line = sentence
    else:                                   #can fit on => add a space then this sentence
        line += ' ' + sentence
```

giving `lines` as:

```
[
 "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Integer in tellus quam.",
 "Nam sit amet iaculis lacus, non sagittis nulla.",
 "Nam blandit quam eget velit maximus, eu consectetur sapien sodales."
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in for this that I can find, so here's a start. You can make it smarter by checking before *and* after for where to move the sentences, instead of just before. Length includes spaces, because I'm splitting naïvely instead of with regular expressions or something.

```
def get_sentences(text, min_length):
    sentences = (sentence + ". "
                 for sentence in text.split(". "))
    current_line = ""
    for sentence in sentences:
        if len(current_line >= min_length):
            yield current_line
            current_line = sentence
        else:
            current_line += sentence
    yield current_line
```

It's slow for long lines, but it does the job.